# alter multiple mysql databases at once (SAAS database changes)

Tags: php, database, deployment, data-migration

We are running a PHP (zend framework) app that creates a database per user (for security/backup/and others reasons).
All these databases have exactly the same structure and that will always be the case. When we deploy new features we'll need to expand all databases with the new fields/tables.

I've read about using dbdeploy for that, but I'm not sure that they support multiple databases at once (without giving in the names one by one). Databases are called user1, user2, user3 and so on.

Are there any good tools that will make this process for us a bit easier and less painful?
We are running phing for automated deployment and found the guide http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy/ not so useful because they don't support multiple databases like we have.

Also, windows or mac mysql clients that can do this are possible for us, so we are open for anything

Comment: Are these databases all on the same server?

Comment: yes, all dbases are on the same server!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a PHP script that I put together for you.  It gets a list of all databases and applies the updates if the database name begins with `user`.

I also have it backup each database before it applies the changes.  The backup portion is specific to Linux/Unix right now, but it can be tweaked to work on other operating systems.

It is pretty verbose at the moment, so you can change it as needed.  You can also change the line terminator, depending if you will be running it from the CLI or a browser.  I would suggest to put this in your scripts directory and run it from the CLI.

Let me know if you need anything else or if this doesn't work for you.

```
<?php
// Configure these as needed
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'password';

$datetime_pattern       = date('Ymd.His');
$backup_file_path       = "/path/to/db_backups/$datetime_pattern/";
$backup_file_format     = "db_backup.%s.sql";
$backup_syntax_pattern  = "/usr/bin/mysqldump --host=%s --user=%s --password=%s --opt %s > $backup_file_path/db_backup.%s.sql";
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// CHANGE THE PERMISSIONS!!!!!!
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
$backup_file_permission = 0777;

// Choose how to terminate your lines
$line_end = "\n";      // Use for CLI
//$line_end = "<br/>";   // Use for browser

// Match words that begin with 'user', case-insensitive
$pattern = '/^user/i';

// What changes will we be applying?
$db_update_syntax = array("ALTER TABLE foo ADD baz1 VARCHAR(30) AFTER bar1",
                          "ALTER TABLE foo ADD baz2 VARCHAR(30) AFTER bar2",
                          "ALTER TABLE foo ADD baz3 VARCHAR(30) AFTER bar3",
                         );

// END OF CONFIGURATION
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Create the database backup directory
if (!mkdir($backup_file_path, $backup_file_permission, true)) {
    die('Failed to create backup directory...');
}

// Connecting to MySQL.
$conn = @mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)
        or die('Not connected : ' . mysql_errno() . ': ' . mysql_error());

$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($conn);

echo "{$line_end}Starting Database Update.{$line_end}";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_list)) {
    $db_name = $row['Database'];
    if (preg_match($pattern, $db_name)) {
        echo "{$line_end}A match was found: [$db_name]{$line_end}";
        echo "Backing up the database{$line_end}";
        // Backup the database
        $backup_syntax = sprintf($backup_syntax_pattern, $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_name);
        exec($backup_syntax);
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn)
                       or die("Can't use [$db_name] : " . mysql_error());

        foreach ($db_update_syntax as $each_update_syntax) {
            echo "Altering using: [$alter_syntax]{$line_end}";
            $update_status = mysql_query($alter_syntax);
            if ($update_status) {
                echo "Success!{$line_end}{$line_end}";
            } else {
                echo "Unable to update [$db_name] : " . mysql_error() . "{$line_end}{$line_end}";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Ignoring: [$db_name]{$line_end}";
    }
}
echo "Finished!{$line_end}";
// Free resources / Close MySQL Connection
mysql_free_result($db_list);
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: I'm checking this one out to see if it can do what we are looking for. Thanks already for posting such a large script!

Comment: can you foresee any problems on a busy database regarding to locking?

Comment: works like a charm on a database without connections. What's your experience on a live database with a lot of users on it?

Comment: I guess the problems depend on the type of transactions and how the queries are coded. According to the documentation [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html ]: `In most cases, ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original table. MySQL incorporates the alteration into the copy, then deletes the original table and renames the new one. While ALTER TABLE is executing, the original table is readable by other sessions. Updates and writes to the table are stalled until the new table is ready, and then are automatically redirected to the new table without any failed updates.`

Comment: Heads up for anyone else using this.  Yes it works, but there are a few errors in it.

e.g. "echo "Altering using: [$alter_syntax]{$line_end}";  

$alter_syntax is never set.  It should be $each_update_syntax

There are a couple more similar errors.  But if you can't sort them out, you definitely should NOT be using a script to alter your databases.

Yes, I could edit the original answer, but I actually don't think these errors are a bad thing if they stop people using this without understanding how it works.